# Customize marker of myLocation Google Maps v2 Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm developing an android application that uses google maps v2. But i have a problem. I want to customize blue dot point(marker) of myLocation that google map gives us. Somebody can tell me how to customize this?? I want to change blue marker for an image and put a info window associated to marker.

Thanks.
Regards.

Answer (score 4):

As of version 3.1.36 of the API v2, the blue dot cannot be changed.

I suggest not enabling the blue dot and instead using `LocationClient` and the location data to display normal `Marker` (optionally with a `Circle` for accuracy). Every time you get a `Location` object, just update `Marker` position.