# Change the Radius Size and the color of the dot of My Current Position

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to change the color of the dot that show My Current Position. Also I want to enlarge the size of the radius the My Current Position.

It is this possible on Android using Google Maps Api?

I can't found how to do it

Thanks

PD: Sorry if my english is not the best

Comment: possible duplicate of [Customize marker of myLocation Google Maps v2 Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003362/customize-marker-of-mylocation-google-maps-v2-android)

Answer (score 0):

Yes..! you can do it using following code..here myMap is object of GoogleMap

```
CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();

circleOptions.center(new LatLng(37.4, -122.1));
circleOptions.radius(1000); // radius of circle in meters
circleOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLUE);//apply stroke with blue
circleOptions.fillColor(Color.RED);// fill circle with red
Circle circle = myMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
```

Comment: But My Current Location is drawed "automatic". If I do what you say, I drawing over the original circle?? My Current Location it have a circle, and dot, by default. I want to change that point and circle. Something like: myLocation.getOptions().setColor("Color").setRadiusSize("size")