# How to current location in Android using google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I'm trying to get the user's Location by showing that he is in which area with Particular location in google maps with the help of Android API while surfing in internet I came to know that getLocationManger() is used to view the Location but it shows only by Latitude,Longitude.

If someone have any idea about this please help me friends.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931103/get-current-location-gmaps/22931253#22931253

Comment: ok Sir let me try this and know for you

Comment: But sir i'd tried androidhive tutorials to get current location by it does not show the map and we can't view where and which location we are it is actually a button is clicked a toastmessage appears as lat,longtitude.

Comment: yes now you get the lat and long values...just store them in two double values(gps.getlatiue(),gps.getlongitude) and place them in your google map.

Comment: ok sir i'll go on with this can you please guide me if futher any doubts.

Comment: ok.but it is very easy.I guess you will implement it by yourself.if any problem arises then inform me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54516/discussion-between-manoj-and-kgandroid).

Answer (score 2):

You can get the user's current location in terms of latitude and longitude and simply make an Implicit Intent to launch map with these values.

To get current location:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Entered onLocationChanged",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("LIFECYCLE","Entered onLocationChanged");
                        lat = location.getLatitude();
                        lon = location.getLongitude();

                }
                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
            };
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
```

To show on google map:

```
Intent intent = null,chooser = null;
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:"+lat+","+lon));
chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent,"Launch Maps");
startActivity(chooser);



/* creating chooser because:
If this is not done, your app may crash when run on the emulator because the emulator may not have an activity installed which can handle the intent.*/
```

Comment: Make sure you have the needed permissions in your Manifest file.
And if u find this useful, click the tick and also upvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location net_loc = null;
lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

you can get the current location from `net_loc`.

Comment: ok Sir let me try this and know for you actually i'm new to android if

Comment: ok Sir let me try this and know for you actually i'm new to android if futher any doubts about this can you please guide me.

Comment: sure @Manoj don't worry.

Comment: sir i'd tried with the above code give by you but it shows me anything no issues can give some explained code to go ahead.

Comment: should i set any thing for net_location

Comment: If you want to get the location from network provider. you can also use `net_loc =lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);`

Comment: `LocationManager lm;
Location location;
lm = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

if(lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
} else if(lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
}`