# How can put GPS icon in android studio?

Tags: android

I am trying this code but don’t show icon:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
} else {
    // Show rationale and request permission.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing only enables the loaction in gmaps. If you want to show current user position on a map then go with that: [Show current loaction in map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931103/get-current-location-gmaps)