# Android MapBox change style of MyLocation marker

Tags: java, android, mapbox, mapbox-marker

I'm using the MapBox API for Android (v5.1). I managed to get it to work all fine and I'm using a custom style (the light style but slightly modified).
I've enabled `MyLocation` and it is also working just fine. But the dot (or marker) that displays my location on the map (in GoogleMaps it's blue) has is light grey so it's barely visible on the map.
[image: Screenshot of the map with marker]
Is there any way to change it's color? I already tried to get the belongong layer but I couldn't find it, neither in the MapBox Studio nor in Android. Where can I customize it?

I found one possible [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003362/customize-marker-of-mylocation-google-maps-v2-android) (althoug it's meant for Google Maps) that would also work but that is - in my opinion - not a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change those settings through the [MyLocationViewSettings](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/api/map-sdk/5.1.0/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/maps/widgets/MyLocationViewSettings.html) object and the method [setForegroundTintColor](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/api/map-sdk/5.1.0/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/maps/widgets/MyLocationViewSettings.html#setForegroundTintColor-int-).

If you already have a MapboxMap, you can configure it through [MapboxMapOptions](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/api/map-sdk/5.1.0/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/maps/MapboxMapOptions.html) when calling newInstance, but you may only [change the accuracy tint color](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/api/map-sdk/5.1.0/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/maps/MapboxMapOptions.html#myLocationAccuracyTint-int-).

Answer (score 0):

Displaying of location is now deprecated in MapboxMap. Recommended solution is to use LocationLayerPlugin.

**EDIT**
Since 0.4.0 Mapbox now has the prefix `mapbox_` before each attribute. The new style names can be found here https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/master/plugin-locationlayer/src/main/res/values/styles.xml.

To change my location marker, you can add custom style into `styles.xml` that is inherited from mapbox_LocationLayer and override mapbox_foregroundDrawable item.

```
<style name="CustomLocationLayer" parent="mapbox_LocationLayer">
    <item name="mapbox_foregroundDrawable">@drawable/location</item>
</style>
```

Then you can create the layer with this style:

```
LocationLayerPlugin(mapView, mapboxMap, locationEngine, R.style.CustomLocationLayer)
```